# Использование методов класса в DLL, определенных в .exe

Tags: c++

**.exe:**

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


// Класс
class MYDLL_API Class
{
public:
    virtual void VirtualFunc(){}

};
```

.cpp(.exe):

```
#include "Funcs.h"
#include <Windows.h>



int main()
{
    // Вызов из .dll метод VirtualFunc
    return 0;
}
```

.dll:

```
#include "Funcs.h"
#include <iostream>

void Class::VirtualFunc()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

.cpp(.dll):

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <Windows.h>


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Я хочу использовать dll в роли "скрипта". Как мне правильно переопределить в dll класс из .exe, а после вызвать его в .exe?

Comment: Уже есть некоторая проблема в коде - функция `Class::VirtualFunc()` определена 2 раза. Ключевое слово  `override` относится к функциям класса-наследника. И встречается не в реализации, а в  определении (т.е.) "внутри " блока `class DerivedClass { ... };`   Я бы советовал сначала написать пример в одном файле cpp, а потом "растаскивать" код на dll и exe.  Что значит 'dll в роли "скрипта"'  тоже не особо понятно.

Comment: @AlexTitov Да, я случайно ночью написал `override`.  dll в роли "скрипта" имелось ввиду, что все функции определенные в exe будут переопределены в dll, а позже вызваны в exe

Comment: Тут есть несколько решений, можно связать динамически можно статически. У обоих способов есть свои как плюсы, так и минусы, выбор способа зависит от решаемых задач. Почитать про  оба можно [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-170)